# Do I need to call Crashlytics.start multiple times?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I've just added my app on [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary). I put the API key in the AndroidManifest.xml file and I call `Crashlytics.start(this)` inside of the `onCreate()` method of my launcher `Activity`.

I've got +20 Activities and 20 Fragments.

Do I need to put `Crashlytics.start(this)` in every Activity's `onCreate()` method in order to make Crashlytics able to track whole my app?

Comment: To solve this you can download a crashlytic's plugin for you IDE. As a benefit it will automatically integrate it into your gradle, Application, Activities. http://try.crashlytics.com/sdk-android/?utm_source=blog&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=Announcing_android_studio_wp&utm_content=CTA_button

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taken from the Crashalytics SDK FAQ:

> If you have an Application subclass, then you can place
>   Crashlytics.start() in the onCreate() method there! Otherwise, if you
>   have multiple launch activities in your app, then add
>   Crashlytics.start(this) to each launch activity. Crashlytics is only
>   initialized the first time you call start, so calling it multiple
>   times won't cause any issues!
>
> http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/206230-can-i-move-crashlytics-start-this-

With this in mind, I think that having started Crashalytics on your `onCreate` method of you launch activity will suffice. Bugsense does more or less the same things and It´s started on the launch Activity only.